# Write from Text files to CSV Files

Tags: python

I am trying to write all the rows that contain the string: from a bunch of Text files. This is my code:

```
import os
import glob
import csv
import re

#Defining Keyword
keyword = '2012-07-02'

#Code to merge all relevant LOG files into one file and insert 
with open('Combined-01022012.txt' , 'w', newline = '') as combined_file:
    csv_output = csv.writer(combined_file)
    for filename in glob.glob('FAO_Agg_2012_Part_*.txt'):
        with open(filename, 'rt', newline = '') as f_input:
        #with gzip.open((filename.split('.')[0]) + '.gz', 'rt', newline='') as f_input:
            csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
            for row in csv_input:
                row.insert(0, os.path.basename(filename))
                try:
                    if keyword in row[2]:
                        csv_output.writerow(row)
                #row.insert(0, os.path.basename(filename))
                #csv_output.writerow(row)
                except:
                    continue
            continue
```

Everything seems to be right and the code runs but nothing gets written on to my text file. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: have you tried adding traces next to your writerow() call to see if it reaches there at least ?
if you want more help you should indeed fix your indentation then provide small example files so we can see what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is in the lines:

```
row.insert(0, os.path.basename(filename))
try:
    if keyword in row[0]:
        csv_output.writerow(row)
except:
    continue
```

You're essentially inserting your parent folder name of the current file as the first entry of your row, and then on the very next line you're checking if that entry (`row[0]`) contains your `keyword`. Unless the parent folder contains your `keyword` (`2012-07-02`) that condition will never evaluate as `True`. I'd mix this up as:

```
if keyword in row[0]:
    csv_output.writerow([os.path.basename(filename)] + row)
```

Also, using blank `except` is a very, very bad idea. If you're looking to capture a specific exception, define it in your `except` clause.